# What can I use to create bright white, non-dissolvable snow?

Tags: model-building

I'm trying to design a class on snow globes, and I would like to have ground snow inside of them.

So far, I can't seem to find anything that is paste-like, bright-white, and non-dissolvable.

I've looked into:

- grout/mortar: dissolves in water
- plaster/stucco: never actually white
- white cement with white sand: possible, but overkill
- air dry white polymer clay: water soluble
- polymer clay: if watered down into a paste, it seems to require mixing in water soluble glue.. maybe acrylic paint will do.  Doesn't harden without baking (not possible for this project)
- flex paste (woodland scenic): water soluble
- flex paste (flex seal): super shiny and rubbery, doesn't seem like it would make good snow
- snow tex/vallejo snow: unsure if it's water resistant.  Can't find the info anywhere

**What can I use as a snowy, bright-white paste that wont dissolve underwater and doesn't require baking?**

Ideally it might look something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRI5lzMUkKA

Comment: Have you tried any snow texture paints yet?

Comment: Added them to the list above.  Snow tex seems to be a "mix with water" thing, so I doubt it dries waterproof.  Vallajo snow says it's a water-based acrylic;  I'm not sure if that means it dries like regular acrylic or not.

Comment: Grout doesn't dissolve in water once set.  That's why it's used between the tiles in showers.  And it can be very bight white.  But I'm not sure how you'd make it look much like snow

Comment: Acrylics should be waterproof; all acrylics are "water-based" paints. I wouldn't go with Snow Tex since it mentions it's for indoor use only, but the ones for model painting are likely a bit more durable so I'd lean toward them.

Comment: PVC pipe cut on a chop saw or table saw makes plastic particles that might work.